# How to call at JSF elements registered java script methods by using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

I have some selectBooleanCheckbox elements in my jsf page. All elements have a javaScript function, which is bind at the attribute "onchange":

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.value_1}" onchange="updating(this, '#{textprop.value_1}', '#specific_html_dom_element');"/>
```

In addition, i have createt a functionality with JQuery to select all availabe selectBooleanCheckboxes in the xhtml jsf page.

JQuery code for select checkboxes:

```
jQuery('.class_1').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {         
    jQuery(this).attr("checked","checked").val("1");
});
```

JQuery code for deselect checkboxes:

```
jQuery('.class_1').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {         
    jQuery(this).attr("checked","").val("0");
});
```

The current problem is, that the java script method "updating" won´t be executed, if the JQuery functionality is executed. If i select or deselect a single selectBooleanCheckbox, the javascript method will be executed. The updating method get different parameter values for each checkbox.

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`onchange` only fires when the user check/uncheck.

You can manually call the onchange event, after setting the value:

```
jQuery('.class_1').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {         
   jQuery(this).attr("checked","checked").val("1");
   jQuery(this).change();// manual call
});
```

or you can trigger the event using:

```
jQuery('.class_1').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {         
   jQuery(this).attr("checked","checked").val("1");
   jQuery(this).trigger("change");
});
```

Hope this helps.